# How to SYNC Redis master-replica on a remote host from a Windows Powershell script?

Tags: linux, powershell, redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

So I'm trying use the `SYNC` Redis command over an ssh session from a PowerShell script to sync data between a master-replica Redis databases (which are hosted on remote Linux hosts). Due to the infrastructure my project has, I cannot have these two databases as a master-replica relationship, so these databases are both masters. **So part of this process involves setting a temporary master-replica relation ship between the two DBs to able to do the `SYNC`.**

So the flow of the script is:

1. Opens a SSH connection to the replica server.
2. Get into Redis-cli tool and Run `SLAVEOF $masterServer $masterPort` to create the master-replica relationship.
3. Run SYNC to sync data between the master-replica.
4. Undo the relationship master - replica and set it to be none replication by running SLAVEOF NO ONE on the replica server.

There's two issues:

1. When the `SYNC` is executed it fails with the following error:
   `SYNC with master failed: -NOMASTERLINK Can't SYNC while not connected with my master` which doesn't makes sense if we check the entire script log output:

```
    18:35:39 Output     : {OK}
    18:35:39 ExitStatus : 0
    18:35:39 Error      : 
    18:35:39 Host       : x.x.x.x
    18:35:39 Duration   : 00:00:00.2536566
    18:35:39 
    18:35:39 
    18:35:39 Output     : {Entering replica output mode...  (press Ctrl-C to quit)}
    18:35:39 ExitStatus : 1
    18:35:39 Error      : SYNC with master failed: -NOMASTERLINK Can't SYNC while not connected with my master
    18:35:39              
    18:35:39 Host       : x.x.x.x
    18:35:39 Duration   : 00:00:00.1155349
```

The first `{OK}` status output is from setting the master-replica relationship. I can confirm that is working because if I execute the script again without undoing the the master-replica relationship, instead `{OK}` status it says `{OK Already connected to specified master}`.
Initially I suspected that it was an async issue, thinking that the `SYNC` was executed to fast before the `echo SLAVEOF $masterServer $masterPort | redis-cli` finishes, but it does not explains what status messages I just mentioned nor the following issues #2. (Though I don't know how to handle async processes  on linux/bash)

2. If I set manually the master-replica relationship to just test the `SYNC` command, it times out  with this error:
   `ForEach-Object : Exception calling "EndExecute" with "1" argument(s): "Command 'echo SYNC | redis-cli' has timed out."` This might be related to the fact that when the `SYNC` command finishes, it puts the bash in a listening state just listening to sequential pings suggesting that connection works, but for escaping this state I must send a Ctrl + C combination which I don't know how to do. I've tried to send `send -- \x03` as an extra command but it does not work. Any idea of how to do this?

Powershell Script:

```
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string] $MasterServer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [string] $MasterPort,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
    [string] $ReplicaServer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3)]
    [string] $UserReplicaServer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=4)]
    [string] $PwdReplicaServer
)

$SecurePasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $PwdReplicaServer -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserReplicaServer, $SecurePasswd)

Write-Host "Connecting to Redis host over SSH..."
# Connect Over SSH and getting session id.
$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $ReplicaServer -Credential $Credentials -Force

if($SessionID -eq $null){
    Write-Host "Error: An error occurred trying to setup the SSH session. Please check the connection string/credentials for the SSH session."
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Host "SSH session created successfully. Running Redis SYNC."
}

# Commands.
$commands = @(
    @{
        Command = "echo SLAVEOF $MasterServer $MasterPort | redis-cli"
        Description = "Configure replication"
    },
    @{
        Command = "echo SYNC | redis-cli"
        Description = "Sync replication"
    },
    @{
        Command = "echo SLAVEOF NO ONE | redis-cli"
        Description = "Undo replication"
    }
)

# Execute commands on Redis Host
foreach ($command in $commands) {
    $result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $SessionID.sessionid -Command $command.Command
    if ($result.ExitStatus -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "Error: Failed to execute command '$($command.Command)'. Description: $($command.Description) Error message: $($result.StandardError)"
        exit 1
    }
    Write-Host "Success: Command '$($command.Command)' executed successfully. Description: $($command.Description)"
}

Write-Host "Script Worked and Finished!"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is a rewrite, I can't be of much help with as to the reason why without actually doing a hands on. But hopefully this helps you a bit.

Here is a re-write that focuses on

- Uses param block with named/indexed parameters
- Uses Pascal casing for parameter names as a best practice
- Displays the result of each command
- Provides error handling for each command
- Iterates through an array of commands and de-duplicates Invoke-SSHCommand

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string] $MasterServer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [string] $MasterPort,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
    [string] $ReplicaServer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3)]
    [string] $UserReplicaServer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=4)]
    [string] $PwdReplicaServer
)

$SecurePasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $PwdReplicaServer -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserReplicaServer, $SecurePasswd)

Write-Host "Connecting to Redis host over SSH..."
# Connect Over SSH and getting session id.
$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $ReplicaServer -Credential $Credentials -Force

if($SessionID -eq $null){
    Write-Host "Error: An error occurred trying to setup the SSH session. Please check the connection string/credentials for the SSH session."
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Host "SSH session created successfully. Running Redis SYNC."
}

# Commands - updated to reflect OP's confirmed working version
$commands = @(
    @{
        Command = "redis-cli SLAVEOF $MasterServer $MasterPort"
        Description = "Configure replication"
    },
    @{

        Command = "redis-cli SYNC & sleep 10 & trap '' INT"
        Description = "Sync replication"
    },
    @{
        Command = "redis-cli SLAVEOF NO ONE"
        Description = "Undo replication"
    }
)
# Execute commands on Redis Host
foreach ($command in $commands) {
    $result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $SessionID.sessionid -Command $command.Command
    if ($result.ExitStatus -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "Error: Failed to execute command '$($command.Command)'. Description: $($command.Description) Error message: $($result.StandardError)"
        exit 1
    }
    Write-Host "Success: Command '$($command.Command)' executed successfully. Description: $($command.Description)"
}

Write-Host "Script Finished! Check For errors"
```

Comment: Thanks for the refactor, I'm kind of new to Powershell, so this going to be great for learning. Just tested the script but I'm having the same issues, though I'll edit the question description with you script refactor, since it's a lot cleaner and comprehensive.

Comment: Does redis have a syslog or a way to print out command history. I'd be interested in seeing how the redis host is interpreting the commands you are sending it.

Comment: Also why pipe echo ... | redis-clis, could you do `redis-cli SLAVEOF $MasterServer $MasterPort` ?

Comment: redis-cli SLAVEOF $MasterServer $MasterPort seems to with another command to execute a CTrl+C. Will post the script as another answer

Comment: @Retrosec6 - thanks for letting us know. Can you confirm updated script and review the answer accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications to the commands and adding `trap '' INT` to execute a Ctrl+C worked.

```
$commands = @(
    @{
        Command = "redis-cli SLAVEOF $MasterServer $MasterPort"
        Description = "Configure replication"
    },
    @{

        Command = "redis-cli SYNC & sleep 10 & trap '' INT"
        Description = "Sync replication"
    },
    @{
        Command = "redis-cli SLAVEOF NO ONE"
        Description = "Undo replication"
    }
)
```